# Device generates special code for web authentication

Tags: security, web, authentication, device

My teachers use a small device, with a press on the only button the device shows a code of numbers.

When they want to change my grades they login to the school system using this code.

*NO I DO NOT WANT TO HACK IT ;)*

I'd like to know how this sort of code is generated and afterwards how it is authenticated?

Comment: The login changes from time to time. The device recieves a key and runs some encryption. The key is probably generate or it could be based on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the device is used for two factor authentication.

RSA makes one type of these devices.  Here is a link to more information on it: [RSA SecurID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_SecurID)

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot of sense! But cant this device be cracked to obtain the public key? Every one with the public key, to call it like that can, if im correct, generate an authorisation code?

Answer (score 1):

The SecurID is not based on time. It used 128 bit RSA algorithm, has a seed value which is a random generated number embedded in the device and mapped to the device serial number.

Comment: thx! But how does the "website" knows that this code is valid?

Comment: It is not authenticated from a website. It is verified by another server known as Authentication Manager, a product of RSA. After being validated from that it passed the accepted or rejected value to the websites.

Comment: As far as i know, these devices have no connection to the outside world or whatsoever